# Downloading .jad or .cod file and installing from website

Tags: blackberry

Actually we have developed java midlet application , that needs to be downloaded through given link. From  nokia , sony , etc we are able to download the application successfully. 
But, when we are accessing the site through BlackBerry , we are not able to download the application . What I am doing wrong here. Whether I need to follow any procedure to install the application in blackberry mobile. Any one help me out of this problem..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening when you click on the JAD file in the BlackBerry browser?  Do you have the MIME types for JAD and COD files set properly in your webserver?  The following link has some useful tips on setting up your server for OTA installations: http://www.berryreview.com/2007/12/10/faq-how-to-install-a-cod-file-ota-over-the-air/

Answer (score 0):

You just place your *jad* and *cod* files onto server and open link to jad in browser (You may use *Browser* class).

Also look at the [RIM Deploy and Distribute guide](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/A70_How_to_Deploy_and_Distribute_Applications_V1.pdf) (section **Over The Air**).

Dont forget unzip your big compiled *cod* file, before placing onto server.